# How to force layout update/resize when child it manages resizes?

Tags: qt

I have a custom `QTextEdit` widget that has it's own resize grip in the corner. I can resize the text widget fine, however the layout it is inside does not change with the resizing of the text edit.

Is there a way to tell the managing layout to recalculate itself based on the independent change in size in one of its widgets?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The layout respects the `sizeHint()` and `minimalSizeHint()` of its children (not their `size()`). So you should reimplement these two virtual methods and return the size you want to force. Whenever your size hint changes, **you should call [`updateGeometry()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#updateGeometry)** on your own widget to trigger an update of the layout where the widget is placed in.

See documentation:

> - [`virtual QSize QWidget::sizeHint() const`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop)
>
>   This property holds the recommended size for the widget.
>   [...]
> - [`virtual QSize QWidget::minimumSizeHint() const`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop)
>
>   This property holds the recommended minimum size for the widget.
>   [...]
>   QLayout will never resize a widget to a size smaller than the minimum size hint unless minimumSize() is set or the size policy is set to QSizePolicy::Ignore. If minimumSize() is set, the minimum size hint will be ignored.

So, to **force a minimum size** of your widget, implement `minimumSizeHint()` by returning your minimum size; to **force a fixed size**, implement both by returning the same size.

I also recommend reading the following section in the documentation page ["Layout Management"](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html#custom-widgets-in-layouts):

> **Custom Widgets in Layouts**
>
> When you make your own widget class, you should also communicate its layout properties. If the widget has a one of Qt's layouts, this is already taken care of. If the widget does not have any child widgets, or uses manual layout, you can change the behavior of the widget using any or all of the following mechanisms:
>
> - Reimplement QWidget::sizeHint() to return the preferred size of the widget.
> - Reimplement QWidget::minimumSizeHint() to return the smallest size the widget can have.
> - Call QWidget::setSizePolicy() to specify the space requirements of the widget.
>
> Call QWidget::updateGeometry() whenever the size hint, minimum size hint or size policy changes. This will cause a layout recalculation. Multiple consecutive calls to QWidget::updateGeometry() will only cause one layout recalculation.

---

**Update (see comments):**

You can also force a size (or height / width only) by calling:

```
QWidget::setFixedSize(QSize);
QWidget::setFixedHeight(int);
QWidget::setFixedWidth(int);
```

These methods simply set the size hints to the given value and call `updateGeometry()` AFAIK. But maybe they do a little bit more since (as seen in the comments) this was the only way I could find to solve the problem here.

Comment: Thanks. I added those functions, but they only seemed to be called when the widgets are first constructed. When I resize the layout, they don't get called again, even though widgets are obviously resizing.

Comment: Did you also try calling `updateGeometry()` afterwards? What layout type are you using? Did you double-check for any mistakes in adding the widget to the layout? Without using your resizing grip, does your `QTextEdit` act as usual to layout changes (resizing of the parent widget)?

Comment: Well, this is what I am doing. I'm not a whiz at Qt or anything. 

http://pastebin.com/mRNLZEAp

I cut out everything that wasn't relevant. If I call updateGeometry() anywhere, I lose the ability to resize the textedit.

Comment: I'm testing a bit and I'd guess that the problem is that the resizing and cursor tracking operations are interfering each other. Give me 10 minutes and we'll see if I can fix this.

Comment: Ok, I got this working using `setFixedHeight` instead of the size hints. You don't need `updateGeometry` in this case. Remove the size hint stuff and replace the two lines `setGeometry( x(), y(), width(), height()-h_diff );` + `size_hint_ = QSize( width(), height()-h_diff );` to the simple call `setFixedHeight(height()-h_diff);`. Another problem arises: If you shrink the text area, the outer widget (window, in this case), doesn't shrink too. You should put the whole thing in a widget that keeps its size as small as possible. I hope I could help you. I add it to my answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. I noticed that you're using more temporary variables than needed. You could simply store the cursor position when it was pressed *relative to the bottom right corner* (measured in positive numbers: `offset = height() - event->y()`), which you can then add to the new cursor position. Then you have your new size (`setFixedHeight(event->y() + offset)`). Independently, I don't think you need to handle the mouse release event. Finally, don't forget to accept (and maybe upvote) the answer, this will give both of us reputation.

Comment: P.S. Thank you for the beer! :)

Comment: thank you. the actual thing that worked for me is just three line of code written in last.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of leemes gave me some insight and I managed to achieve resize of a QTextWidget inside a layout among other controls using custom SizeGrip control. Note that at least one scroll bar should be visible in order to have visible size grip.

It was necessary to reimplement the widget's `sizeHint()` method:

```
QSize MultilineTextEdit::sizeHint() const
{
    return size();
}
```

Then at the end of `mouseMoveEvent()` of my SizeGrip widget I added

```
void SizeGrip::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
    // note that this is not the full code of the method
    ...
    // save the old minimum and maximum size of the widget (w) resized by the grip
    QSize oldMin = w->minimumSize();
    QSize oldMax = w->maximumSize();

    w->setFixedSize(nr.size()); // nr is the new rect of the widget

    w->setMinimumSize(oldMin);
    w->setMaximumSize(oldMax);
}
```

The SizeGrip widget was inspired by the QSizeGrip class which operates on the top level parent window directly. SizeGrip operates on its direct parent widget instead.