# Can't refesh pixmap of QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, refresh, qpixmap, qlabel

I have been stuck on this issue for 2 days now. I'm using the `Qt` plugin for `Visual Studio 2013` on `Window 7-64 bit`.

I have been trying to display a pair of images in `QLabel`s. I need to manipulate the pixel data regularly, so I store them in `QImage`s, and every time I want to refresh the display I set the `QPixmap` of a `QLabel`. The problem is, it only seems to refresh if I change/move the window in some way.

This problems goes away if I just make the `QLabel`s children of my `QWidget`, but never set a layout. If I then add `repaint()` or `update()`, the problem comes back.

(this is a very similar post to one I posted using `QGraphicsScene`, but the problem seems to be more fundamental than that, so I am reposting)

Here is my code. First the .h

```
#ifndef DISPLAYWIDGET_H
#define DISPLAYWIDGET_H

#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QLabel>

#define FULLSCALE 255
#define IM_X_MIN -5.0
#define IM_X_MAX 5.0
#define IM_Z_MIN 0.0
#define IM_Z_MAX 15.0
#define IM_PIXEL_WIDTH 200
#define IM_PIXEL_HEIGHT IM_PIXEL_WIDTH * (IM_Z_MAX-IM_Z_MIN)/(IM_X_MAX - IM_X_MIN)
#define BORDER_WIDTH    10
#define RAND_SEED 7

class DisplayWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    DisplayWidget(int width, int height, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~DisplayWidget();

private:
    QLabel* bimageLabel;
    QLabel* dimageLabel;
    QImage* bImage;
    QImage* dImage;
    QTimer* frameGrab;
    QPushButton* debugButton;

    void CreateWidgets();
    void SetupGui();

    int w, h;

public slots:
    void GenerateNewData();
};

#endif // DISPLAYWIDGET_H
```

and the .cpp.

```
#include "displaywidget.h"

DisplayWidget::DisplayWidget(int width, int height, QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent)
{
    //ui.setupUi(this);

    w = width;
    h = height;

    CreateWidgets();
    SetupGui();

    // seed the random number generator
    srand(RAND_SEED);
    GenerateNewData();
}

DisplayWidget::~DisplayWidget()
{
}

void DisplayWidget::CreateWidgets()
{
    bImage = new QImage(w, h, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    dImage = new QImage(w, h, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    bimageLabel = new QLabel(this);
    dimageLabel = new QLabel(this);

    debugButton = new QPushButton("DEBUG", this);
    bimageLabel->setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: black};");
    dimageLabel->setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: white};");

    frameGrab = new QTimer(this);
}

void DisplayWidget::SetupGui()
{
    QHBoxLayout * layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    setLayout(layout); // commenting this line out makes it refresh
    layout->addWidget(bimageLabel);
    layout->addWidget(dimageLabel);
    layout->addWidget(debugButton);

    connect(frameGrab, SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(GenerateNewData()));
    connect(debugButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(GenerateNewData()));
    frameGrab->start(50);
}

void DisplayWidget::GenerateNewData()
{
    QRgb * bImageData = (QRgb *)bImage->scanLine(0);
    QRgb * dImageData = (QRgb *)dImage->scanLine(0);

    for (int i; i < w * h; i++)
    {
        bImageData[i] = qRgba(rand() % FULLSCALE, 0, 0, FULLSCALE);
        dImageData[i] = qRgba(0, 0, rand() % FULLSCALE, FULLSCALE);
    }

    bimageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*bImage).scaled(QSize(IM_PIXEL_WIDTH, IM_PIXEL_HEIGHT)));
    dimageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*dImage).scaled(QSize(IM_PIXEL_WIDTH, IM_PIXEL_HEIGHT)));

    //this->update(); // this breaks it again
}
```

Losing my mind here. I have very limited experience with `Qt`, but I believe I have the right approach.

Please help!

Comment: I suspect it has to do with your layout and sizehint. Refer to this post for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758267/how-to-force-layout-update-resize-when-child-it-manages-resizes

Comment: Thank for your response. I don't think I was able to pick out exactly what you think might be the issue. What functions typically get called when you move/resize/click a button on a widget? Updating geometry doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I haven't given you an answer, as I've not worked with Qt recently, but my suspicion is that the size of the layout does not change after calling setPixmap again. You could create a derived label that returns the correct sizehint after being updated. You may even cache the images in the (dervived) label

Comment: Perhaps I'm being stupid at the moment, but what I would like to have happen is the image pixels refresh while the size of the image stays the same. When does the sizehint change?

Comment: I've tested the code on Ubuntu. I've modified the style to use grey and black just to see the labels a bit better. I've removed the timer as to not interfere with your debug button. The layout works as expected. It lays out the button and to labels horizontally.
Whether or not calling update makes no difference (as changing the pixmap on the label causes an udpate). When the button is pressed, the image is updated, with the size scaled, and therefore constant as expected. Not sure what behaviour you are expecting...

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code on Ubuntu. I can unfortunately not comment on windows. I've modified the code slightly (See comments marked by //@w:):

```
#include "displaywidget.h"

DisplayWidget::DisplayWidget(int width, int height, QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent)
{
    w = width;
    h = height;

    CreateWidgets();
    SetupGui();

    // seed the random number generator
    srand(RAND_SEED);
    GenerateNewData();
}

DisplayWidget::~DisplayWidget()
{
}

void DisplayWidget::CreateWidgets()
{
    bImage = new QImage(w, h, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    dImage = new QImage(w, h, QImage::Format_ARGB32);

    bimageLabel = new QLabel(this);
    bimageLabel->setScaledContents(true);

    dimageLabel = new QLabel(this);
    dimageLabel->setScaledContents(true);

    debugButton = new QPushButton("DEBUG", this);
    bimageLabel->setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: black};");
    dimageLabel->setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: grey};");

    frameGrab = new QTimer(this);
}

void DisplayWidget::SetupGui()
{
    //@w: Adding vertical layout as button below seems like better usage of space...
    QVBoxLayout * vlay = new QVBoxLayout();

    QHBoxLayout * hlay = new QHBoxLayout();
    hlay->addWidget(bimageLabel);
    hlay->addWidget(dimageLabel);
    vlay->addLayout(hlay);
    vlay->addWidget(debugButton);

    //@w: Removing size constraints on top layout allows me to resize window and see effect.
    vlay->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetNoConstraint);
    setLayout(vlay); // commenting this line out makes it refresh

    connect(frameGrab, SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(GenerateNewData()));
    //@w: I suppose we can chuck the button.... Currently it serves no purpose
    connect(debugButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(GenerateNewData()));

    //@w: Timer slower initially, then increase to see where performance degrades.
    frameGrab->start(200);
}

void DisplayWidget::GenerateNewData()
{
    QRgb * bImageData = (QRgb *)bImage->scanLine(0);
    QRgb * dImageData = (QRgb *)dImage->scanLine(0);

    //@w: This code just varies the contents by having a b and d selector that
    //    alternates colour... Simple stuff...
    int bSelect = rand() % 3,
        dSelect = (bSelect==2) ? 0 : bSelect+1;

    for (int i = 0; i < w * h; i++)
    {
        //@w: 3 colours, only two being selected - can be improved, I suppose.
        QRgb rgb[3] =
        {
          (bSelect == 0) || (dSelect==0) ? qRgba(rand() % FULLSCALE, 0, 0, FULLSCALE) : 0,
          (bSelect == 1) || (dSelect==1) ? qRgba(0, rand() % FULLSCALE, 0, FULLSCALE) : 0,
          (bSelect == 2) || (dSelect==2) ? qRgba(0, 0, rand() % FULLSCALE, FULLSCALE) : 0,
        };

        bImageData[i] = rgb[bSelect];
        dImageData[i] = rgb[dSelect];
    }

    //@w: Removed scaling, as it depends on layout...
    bimageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*bImage));
    dimageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*dImage));
}
```

Initially the labels take its size from the pixmaps. Thereafter the labels adhere to the layout, which adheres to resizing of the form (main/parent widget)

Answer (score 0):

QtForum solved this one for me, and boy is it embarassing.

I forgot to initialize the loop counter. Fixed everything.